# duplicate name checking function for an array

Tags: c++

I am still a beginner in C++, so I'm sorry if the question is simple.

I am trying to build a program that asks you to input names and register them to an array. Then, I need to call a function to check if there are any duplicate names. If there are any, it asks the user to input another name.

The problem I'm having is that the function is called whether or not there are duplicates, and always replaces the first name that was entered.

```
int checking(string stringArray[5]) {
int i, z ;
for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (z = 0; z < 5; z++) {
        if (z != i) { // Makes sure don't check number against itself
            if (stringArray[z] == stringArray[i]) {
                return i;
            }
            else {
                return 0;
int main(){ 
 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    cin >> stringArray[i];
}
 j = checking(stringArray);
  if (j == 0) {
    cout << "Please re-enter name " << ". Duplicate names are not allowed" 
    <<'\n';
    cin >> stringArray[j];

}
```

Comment: Welcome to C++. The first thing you're going to want to learn about is Standard Library containers like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). Passing around C-style arrays of things is not ideal. In this case `checking` should be `size_t checking(const std::vector<std::string>& array)` or something like that to avoid copies.

Comment: At first glance, you are missing #includes. Please see what MCVE is, and provide one.

Comment: Recommendation: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html - this is formatted horribly.

Comment: Another thing, since you are a beginner, you should indent your code properly. Even experts do that, to be able to see what code does clearly, so I am a bit flabbergasted every time a beginner thinks they are better and don't need to do it. Use an editor which can auto-indent or auto-format the code for you.

Comment: checking() is missing 5 close parens.  main() missing 1 close paren.

Comment: in my code i have included the libraries and  the parens but i figured that is better not to include them to my question for condensation purposes

Comment: *but i figured that is better not to include them to my question for condensation purposes*  -- The include's take up maybe 2 or 3 extra lines.  That hardly is worth leaving out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some observations (ignoring the syntax errors, I assume these are not present in your actual code):

1. z doesn't need to start at 0 every time, it can start at i + 1 because you dont need to check pairs you have already checked (makes it simpler and runs faster)
2. you don't want to return in your loop, it will prevent you from checking past the first repeated name. Instead move your reenter statement into the loop.
3. generally you dont want to use literals (5) in a loop, instead use a variable to store the length of the array and compare to that (this is just a general programming rule, it won't change how the code runs)

Your final checking() function should look closer to:

```
void checking(string stringArray[5]) {
    int i, z ;
    // consider replacing 5 with a variable
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (z = i+1; z < 5; z++) {
            if (stringArray[z] == stringArray[i]) {
                cout << "Please re-enter name " << 
                ". Duplicate names are not allowed" <<'\n';
                cin >> stringArray[z];
                /* restart the loop user may have entered a */ 
                /* second duplicate from previous entries */
                i = 0;
                z=i+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```